# Is the State and Notification Broker API available in Windows CE 6.0

Tags: msdn, windows-ce

The MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154480.aspx) indicates that this API is not limited to Windows Mobile, but is available in CE 6.0. The documentation says that I should link against aygshell.lib, but this lib file doesn't contain the correct methods.

A search of the WINCE600 tree turns up a reference to k.coredll.dll, but this should be accessible from user mode applications. Is there some component (beyond AYGShell API itself) that must be included in the OS to gain access to this API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires setting SYSGEN_STATE_NOTIFICATIONS=1.